# "Internal Error" when connecting to wifi - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, toshiba

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Toshiba Satellite C850 laptop, ethernet works fine but I can't connect via wifi, I get an "Internal Error" message; what could be wrong? And how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing proprietary drivers. Here's how to do it:

1. Go to Software Center
2. Edit -> Software Sources
3. Additional drivers tab